# Maven Multi-Module Dependency Compile Problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I am having some problem with my maven dependencies in a multi-module project using IntelliJ.

The following is the structure of my maven modules:
(1) `venus` is the root module.
(2) `architect` is the parent module of `architect-com` module.
(3) `actions-com` is the child module of `actions` module and `services` is the parent module of `actions` module.
(4) `architect` and `services` are direct children of the root module

```
- venus
  - architect
    - architect-com
      - src [java classes here]
  - services
    - actions
      - actions-com
         - src [java classes here]
```

architect, services and actions modules don't have a src folder (I deleted them because I think parent modules don't need the src folders.)

Here are the POM of the modules.

**// Venus - Root module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>co.shock</groupId>
    <artifactId>venus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>services</module>
        <module>services/actions</module>
        <module>services/actions/actions-com</module>
        <module>architect</module>
        <module>architect/architect-com</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

**// architect**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>venus</artifactId>
        <groupId>co.shock</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <name>architect</name>
    <groupId>co.shock.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>architect</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>architect-com</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**// architect-com**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <artifactId>architect</artifactId>
        <groupId>co.shock.venus</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <name>Architect - Com</name>
    <groupId>co.shock.venus.architect</groupId>
    <artifactId>architect-com</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
      // SPRING AND HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES HERE
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**// services**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <artifactId>venus</artifactId>
        <groupId>co.shock</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <name>Services</name>
    <groupId>co.shock.venus</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>actions</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**// actions**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
        <groupId>co.shock.venus</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <name>Services - Actions</name>
    <groupId>co.shock.venus.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>actions</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>actions-com</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**// actions-com**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <artifactId>actions</artifactId>
        <groupId>co.shock.venus.services</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <name>Services - Actions - Com</name>
    <groupId>co.shock.venus.services.actions</groupId>
    <artifactId>actions-com</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.shock.venus.architect</groupId>
            <artifactId>architect-com</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The `actions-com` module imports `architect-com` as can be seen in de above pom. When i compile the `actions-com` module i get the following errors:

```
C:\3_projects\venus\services\actions\actions-com>mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------< co.shock.venus.services.actions:actions-com >---------
[INFO] Building Services - Actions - Com 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.256 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-29T21:02:12+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project actions-com: Could not resolve dependencies for project co.shock
.venus.services.actions:actions-com:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at co.shock.venus
.architect:architect-com:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for co.shock.venus
.architect:architect-com:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact co.shock:venus:pom:1.0-S
NAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The following is the path to my `.m2` repository where architect-com is built. Here is the content of the snapshot folder

```
C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\co\shock\venus\architect\architect-com\1.0-SNAPSHOT
   - _remote.repositories
   - architect-com-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   - architect-com-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
   - maven-metadata-local.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer indicates that this question was resolved by "typo / unrepro" and thus it can be closed. The answer is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the last sentence of the error msg: `Could not find artifact co.shock:venus:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT`

`services` contains:

```xml
    <parent>
        <artifactId>venus</artifactId>
        <groupId>co.shock</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

but **Venus** contains:

```
    <groupId>co.shock</groupId>
    <artifactId>jupiter</artifactId> <!-- should be 'venus' -->
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

You simply mixed up the planets. :)

Comment: If an `install` is needed the build configuration is simply wrong.

Comment: @Gerold Broser i have updated my post. You can read the last but one paragraph. I have built the architect-com module already.

Comment: @EddyFreeman You declared all your modules in `venus` and again in `architect` _and_ `services` _and_ `actions`. I've never seen that. Declare just `services` and `architect` in `venus`. The aggregation hierarchy  is recognized by Maven.

Comment: @GeroldBroser I have rectified the venus/jupiter mixed up. Actually it was a typo in the post. I have also removed the modules from venus pom except services and architect. None of these changes have solved the problem though.

Comment: @GeroldBroser In your answer you mentioned about the last error msg: "Could not find artifact co.shock:venus:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT". The compilation of "actions-com" module is given the errors but do you know why it is also complaining about the "venus SNAPSHOT"?

Comment: @EddyFreeman Can you update the question with the changed declarations and the (possibly new) error msg. And, BTW, `architect` above still contains `jupiter` as parent.

Comment: @GeroldBroser it seems that it is working now. So i have accepted your answer